# Как создать n-мерный массив в GoLang?

Tags: массивы, golang, матрицы

Как создать n-мерный массив в GoLang? Например как в Python numpy, где можно создать массив нулей одной функцией `numpy.zeros([n чисел])`

Comment: То есть например есть какая - то функция, которой я передаю n и она вернёт n-мерный массив из 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте масса такой конструкцией, указав размерности и тип: `[2][2][3]int{}`. Все значения при этом будут инициализированы нулями. Пример:

```go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    sample := [2][2][3]int{}

    fmt.Println(sample[0][0][0])
    fmt.Println(sample[1][1][1])
    fmt.Println(sample[1][1][2])
}
```

---

В виду статической типизации, создать массив неопределённой размерности на лету невозможно. Но если очень надо, то можно создать абстракцию: одномерный массив и код для работы с ним, который будет вести себя как многомерный. массив заданной размерности, конвертируя многомерные индексы в одномерные. Для двумерного массива формула следующая: `matrix[ i ][ j ] = array[ i*w + j ]`, где `w` – ширина матрицы, `i` – индекс по вертикали, `j` – индекс по горизонтали ([подробнее здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14015556/5308802)). Аналогично можно реализовать обращение по нескольким индексам, в том числе заранее неопределённому значению.

**Update.** Накидал подобный код:

```go
package main

import "fmt"

type MDArray struct {
    Dims     int
    Sizes    []int
    Weights  []int
    Data     []int
}

func CreateMDArray(sizes []int) MDArray {
    total := 1
    weights := make([]int, len(sizes))
    weights[0] = 1
    for i, v := range sizes {
        total *= v
        if i > 0 {
            weights[i] = weights[i-1] * sizes[i-1]
        }
    }
    obj := MDArray {
        Dims:    len(sizes),
        Sizes:   sizes,
        Weights: weights,
        Data:    make([]int, total),
    }
    return obj
}

func (obj MDArray) MakeIndex(keys []int) int {
    index := 0
    for i, v := range obj.Weights {
        index += keys[i] * v
    }
    return index
}

func (obj MDArray) Get(keys []int) int {
    return obj.Data[obj.MakeIndex(keys)]
}

func (obj MDArray) Set(keys []int, value int) {
    obj.Data[obj.MakeIndex(keys)] = value
}

func main() {
    // Создаём объект многомерного массива
    array := CreateMDArray([]int{3, 2, 5})
    // Поставим значения равным одномерным индексам
    for i, _ := range array.Data {
        array.Data[i] = i
    }
    // Итого в массиве 30 элементов, последний будет иметь индекс 29
    fmt.Println(array.MakeIndex([]int{2, 1, 4}))
    // Поставим ему значение -1
    array.Set([]int{2, 1, 4}, -1)
    // Отобразим внутренний одномерный массив
    fmt.Println(array.Data)
    // Получим: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
    //           17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 -1]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь, динамически создать N-размерный массив, не зная количество его сторон, не получится.

А так, можно использовать `make`, если заранее неизвестно сколько элементов в нем:

```
N := 3

arr := make([]int, N)
fmt.Println(arr)
// [0 0 0]

arr[0] = 999
fmt.Println(arr)
// [999 0 0]
```

2-х размерность:

```
N := 3

matrix := make([][]int, N)
for i := range matrix {
    matrix[i] = make([]int, N)
}
```